# image not showing on the left of tableview in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have created a simple table view containg an image on the left side .it works fine in the simulator,but when connected to a device,i m not getting the image on the left side of the tableview and also the splash screen.I ve even gave a clean built its working on the simulator but not on the device.

```
NSString *imgSource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sug" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imgSource];
cell.imageView.image=img;
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget to add the image to your xcode project. And try this

cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name of the image with type"];

Comment: thanks man dat worked...i m having another problem i m not getting the splash screen.. i ve named my image Default.png.it works good in simulator but not on device..any idea

Comment: Is the image Default.png also named liked that in ur projects folder?

Comment: i jst put an image named Default.png...shld i change any other stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think you something missing to add image in your project resource folder. 
Please try this it may help you drag and drop your images in your resource folder of project. during this process don't forget to click on "**Copy items into destination group's folder"** 
and pressed add. Then cleaning all target try again on your device.